# Extra space below footer in Ratina 5K/4K screen (max-width related)

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have been encountering this problem quite often and never got to solve one. The problem is every time I open in a 2560 width or bigger screen like 4k or 5k (in this case iMac 5K), I discover an extra space below the footer.

However, when I set the container's width to regular width instead of max-width, the space disappears but I want to maintain the max-width while enabling the full page layout. What I don't get is that since there is no explicit width or height on footer, it should not affect the footer right? And this problem occurs on Bootstrap as well when using a regular container instead of container-fluid.

What would be the best way to fix this problem?

Thank you.

```css
/* Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Main Styling */
html,body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

/* Utility Classes */
.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  width:100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.text-primary {
  color: #f7c08a;
}

.lead {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #f7c08a;
  color: #333;
}

.btn-light {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #333;
}

.bg-dark {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-light {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #333;
}

.bg-primary {
  background: #f7c08a;
  color: #333;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}

.l-heading {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

/* Padding */
.py-1 { padding: 10px 0; }
.py-2 { padding: 20px 0; }
.py-3 { padding: 30px 0; }

/* Navbar */
#navbar {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}

#navbar a {
  color: #fff;
}

#navbar .logo {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

#navbar ul li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover, 
#navbar ul li a.current {
  background: #444;
  color: #f7c08a;
}

/* Showcase */
#showcase {
  background: url('../img/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 600px;
}

#showcase .showcase-content {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 170px;
}

#showcase .showcase-content h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

#showcase .showcase-content p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

/* Home Info */
#home-info {
  height: 450px;
} 

#home-info .info-img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: url('../img/photo-1.jpg') no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#home-info .info-content {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#home-info .info-content p {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Features */
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align:center;
}

.box i {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* About Info */
#about-info .info-right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#about-info .info-right img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#about-info .info-left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Testimonials */
#testimonials {
  height: 100%;
  background: url('../img/test-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

#testimonials h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#testimonials .testimonial {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#testimonials .testimonial img {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Contact Form */
#contact-form .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#contact-form label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#contact-form input, 
#contact-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
}

#contact-form textarea {
  height: 200px;
}

#contact-form input:focus, 
#contact-form textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #f7c08a;
}

/* Footer */
#main-footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">HBT</a></h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="current" href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section id="about-info" class="bg-light py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="info-left">
        <h1 class="l-heading"><span class="text-primary">About</span> Hotel BT</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem veritatis illo, similique labore voluptate nulla animi dolorum eius laborum illum, nesciunt quod reprehenderit dicta autem vel nobis minima sit deleniti!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A velit voluptatem impedit voluptate. Doloribus, voluptas dolore! Cupiditate aliquid sequi deserunt.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="info-right">
        <img src="./img/photo-2.jpg" alt="hotel">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="clr"></div>

  <section id="testimonials" class="py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="l-heading">What Our Guests Say</h2>
      <div class="testimonial bg-primary">
        <img src="./img/person-1.jpg" alt="Samantha">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam eligendi quibusdam, dolorum maxime cum numquam quisquam, deleniti eum incidunt, velit non consectetur. Facere, ipsa maxime, ullam id amet odio laboriosam sit iusto tempore fugit exercitationem, a dolore quo maiores nisi!</p>
      </div>

      <div class="testimonial bg-primary">
          <img src="./img/person-2.jpg" alt="Jen">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam eligendi quibusdam, dolorum maxime cum numquam quisquam, deleniti eum incidunt, velit non consectetur. Facere, ipsa maxime, ullam id amet odio laboriosam sit iusto tempore fugit exercitationem, a dolore quo maiores nisi!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer id="main-footer">
    <p>Hotel BT &copy; 2019, All RIghts Reserved</p>
  </footer>
```

[image: When viewed on a widescreen]

[image: Looks fine on laptop screen]

Comment: That is normal behaviour, your viewport height is bigger than your website `body`

Comment: What I don't fully understand is that shouldn't everything just pile up and automatically fit everything horizontally? I did not set the explicit height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a "Holy Grail" layout where the footer is always attached to the bottom. To achieve that, you need flexbox to expand the middle section to fill the space. I added a wrapper, but you could feasibly apply the styles to .holy-grail-layout to the body if there aren't other elements that might mess with it. Also, I wrapped everything outside the header & footer with a div set to flex-grow: 1;

```css
/* Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Main Styling */
html,body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

/* Utility Classes */
.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  width:100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.text-primary {
  color: #f7c08a;
}

.lead {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #f7c08a;
  color: #333;
}

.btn-light {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #333;
}

.bg-dark {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-light {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #333;
}

.bg-primary {
  background: #f7c08a;
  color: #333;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}

.l-heading {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

/* Padding */
.py-1 { padding: 10px 0; }
.py-2 { padding: 20px 0; }
.py-3 { padding: 30px 0; }

/* Navbar */
#navbar {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}

#navbar a {
  color: #fff;
}

#navbar .logo {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

#navbar ul li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover, 
#navbar ul li a.current {
  background: #444;
  color: #f7c08a;
}

/* Showcase */
#showcase {
  background: url('../img/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 600px;
}

#showcase .showcase-content {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 170px;
}

#showcase .showcase-content h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

#showcase .showcase-content p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

/* Home Info */
#home-info {
  height: 450px;
} 

#home-info .info-img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: url('../img/photo-1.jpg') no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#home-info .info-content {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#home-info .info-content p {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Features */
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align:center;
}

.box i {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* About Info */
#about-info .info-right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#about-info .info-right img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#about-info .info-left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Testimonials */
#testimonials {
  height: 100%;
  background: url('../img/test-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

#testimonials h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#testimonials .testimonial {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#testimonials .testimonial img {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Contact Form */
#contact-form .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#contact-form label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#contact-form input, 
#contact-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
}

#contact-form textarea {
  height: 200px;
}

#contact-form input:focus, 
#contact-form textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #f7c08a;
}

/* Footer */
#main-footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Holy Grail Layout */
.holy-grail-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
header, footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.content-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="holy-grail-layout">
    <header>
      <nav id="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">HBT</a></h1>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="current" href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <section id="about-info" class="bg-light py-3">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="info-left">
            <h1 class="l-heading"><span class="text-primary">About</span> Hotel BT</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem veritatis illo, similique labore voluptate nulla animi dolorum eius laborum illum, nesciunt quod reprehenderit dicta autem vel nobis minima sit deleniti!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A velit voluptatem impedit voluptate. Doloribus, voluptas dolore! Cupiditate aliquid sequi deserunt.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="info-right">
            <img src="./img/photo-2.jpg" alt="hotel">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div class="clr"></div>

      <section id="testimonials" class="py-3">
        <div class="container">
          <h2 class="l-heading">What Our Guests Say</h2>
          <div class="testimonial bg-primary">
            <img src="./img/person-1.jpg" alt="Samantha">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam eligendi quibusdam, dolorum maxime cum numquam quisquam, deleniti eum incidunt, velit non consectetur. Facere, ipsa maxime, ullam id amet odio laboriosam sit iusto tempore fugit exercitationem, a dolore quo maiores nisi!</p>
          </div>

          <div class="testimonial bg-primary">
              <img src="./img/person-2.jpg" alt="Jen">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam eligendi quibusdam, dolorum maxime cum numquam quisquam, deleniti eum incidunt, velit non consectetur. Facere, ipsa maxime, ullam id amet odio laboriosam sit iusto tempore fugit exercitationem, a dolore quo maiores nisi!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
    </div>

    <footer id="main-footer">
      <p>Hotel BT &copy; 2019, All RIghts Reserved</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you want the image in the preview to stretch, you may have to set it outside of the content-wrapper and set it to flex-grow: 1; as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did solve my mystery why it was behaving that way. Now I have two more questions lol..
1. While the footer is now at the bottom, there seems to be an extra space between section and footer. Why is that? 
2. Any reason for position relative?  
Thanks :)

Comment: #2 You are right, position relative isn't needed, I removed it from my anser.

Comment: #1: Flex-grow just fills unused space by stretching. The contents inside however, aren't stretching with it. You would probably have to use the same principle to stetch a graphic to fill the space if you want it seamless. Most people probably won't view it on that large of a screen though, so you may want to weigh the benefits/dev time. My first comment might be a solution. If you have two elements set to flex-grow: 1, they will both share available space to fill the unused area.

Comment: I see. Thanks for replying my questions one by one. Love your photographs. I will have to keep practicing using flex.